# how to keep a hash value in the table column in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, hash

i am very new to rails . I am having a table holding all users basic information like

**users(id,name,email)**
now i am trying to keep some additional information of these users in a separate table like

**user_details(id,user_id,additional_info)**

I have created this user_details table . Now i try to keep some default records for checking . how to keep the hash value of the user's additional details in the additional_info like if my additional details are **user's (designation,salary,prjtname)** in the column additional_info of the User_details table.

Also what **datatype** i have to give for this **additional_info column** of the **User_details** table. Please give some suggestions ..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The data type for that column must be text so in your migrations you can specify:

```
add_column :user_details, :additional_info, :text
```

Then in your model you have to specify that this column will contain a hash and you do that with the serialize command:

```
class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :additional_info
```

After that you can save hash information.

```
@ud = UserDetail.new
@ud.additional_info = {:salary => 1000000}
@ud.save
```

Comment: didn't know about "serialize". +1

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL 5.7.8 there is a support for a native JSON data type, so saving a hash is much more direct and can be searchable and more:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: It might be good to add a code example (in case the link breaks in the future).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use [JSON fields](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb) on the model. The migration would have something like:

```
create_table :events do |t|
  t.json 'payload'
end
```