# can't duo nil class when saving Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save a Hash in my table.The coulmn datatype is text and i have serialized the column in model.But while saving the value in the column it throws an error

```
TypeError: can't dup NilClass from /home/ajit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sanitize-1.0.8/lib/sanitize.rb:69:in `dup'
```

Migration file looks like this

```
class AddColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def self.up  
    add_column :xyz, :column_name, :text  
  end
end
```

In Model file i have serialized as this.

```
serialize :column_name, Hash
```

Comment: What are you trying to save?

Comment: I am trying to save a hash value.

Comment: @Ajit `serialize :column_name` and send the hash data to the column and save it works check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386545/how-to-keep-a-hash-value-in-the-table-column-in-rails

Comment: @anusha I checked that, but it doesn't works in my case.I am using sanitize gem.the error is thrown by the gem.